# Como hacer que un Formulario contenga varios modelos para validar

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

Tengo este viewmodel

```
 public class Daticos
    {
        public Preuba Preuba { get; set; }       
        public Usuario Usuarios { get; set; }
    }
```

Que contiene dos modelos, que esos dos modelos contiene los mismos datos (o campos de una tabla), lo que quiero hacer es que mediante un solo formulario se envie esa información a esos dos modelos

```
@model CreateCRUD.Models.ViewModels.Daticos

    <form asp-action="Create">
                <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label"></label>
                    <input type="text"  asp-for="Usuarios.Nombre" />
                    <span asp-for="Usuarios.Edad" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
                <br />
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label"></label>
                    <input type="text"  asp-for="Usuarios.Edad" />
                    <span asp-for ="Usuarios.Edad" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
                <br />    
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" />
                </div>
            </form>
```

Este formulario como tal solo valida un solo Modelo, la pregunta es como hacer que valide los dos modelos y se cree.

Este es mi controlador, que como tal si me sirve para crear un solo modelo, pero al intentar crear los dos claramente me produce un error

```
 [HttpPost]
            [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
            public IActionResult Create(Daticos daticos, string checkbox)
            {
                if (ModelState.IsValid)
           {
                    //_context.Preubas.Add(daticos.Preuba);
                    _context.Usuario.Add(daticos.Usuarios);
                    _context.SaveChanges();
    
                   
                    return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
                }
```

Los dos modelos

```
   public class Usuario
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
         public string Nombre { get; set; }
        public int Edad { get; set; }
    }
   public class Preuba
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Nombres { get; set; }
        public string? Apellido { get; set; }
        public int Edad { get; set; }
    }
```

El error que me aparece es 'Value cannot be null. Arg_ParamName_Name',

Comment: Edita la pregunta y agrega lo que contiene tus clases internas del ViewModel. Por otro lado, ¿qué error te genera al intentar agregar información a 2 DbSets ?

Comment: ¿Seguro que en ambos DbSets y en las tablas generadas, "Name" es inexistente?

Comment: El caso no es eso, solo quiero saber si en un formulario se puede tener varios modelos, como en este <input type="text"  asp-for="Usuarios.Nombre" />, que solo hace la validacion o verificación de un modelo para ser enviado a la tabla Usuario

Comment: Lectura altamente recomendada: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/validation?view=aspnetcore-7.0 Saludos.